# VBA to Copy Cells When Condition Is Met

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code to copy some of the cells in a row to another sheet when a condition is met.

The problem is, this only works if the data on sheet one begins in column A but I want my data to start in Column B for aesthetic reasons.

Here is the code I have written which only works if my data starts in Column A.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long


'to check the last filled row on sheet named one

lastrow = Worksheets("one").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

If Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Mobile" Then

    Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 1).Copy

    erow = Worksheets("two").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("two").Cells(erow + 1, 1)

    Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 3).Copy

    Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("two").Cells(erow + 1, 2)

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

What amendment would I need to make to my code to run with Column A empty?
I'm assuming I would need to change the following;

If Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Mobile" Then to If Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Mobile" Then

Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 3).Copy to Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 4).Copy

However these amendments still do not work.

[Image of Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcYO0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right line of thinking with the suspected change you need to make but your code is failing on the 'lastrow = ' line because that is still looking for the last used cell in column A.

Therefore you will need to change:

```
lastrow = Worksheets("one").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

to

```
lastrow = Worksheets("one").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then check and change the rest of your lines, as you have correctly suspected you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the column index to the one you want in this line of code:

```
 Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 1).Copy
```

For instance, if you want to copy from column B (index 2) instead column A (index 1), then change "1" to "2".